# Simple proof that $2019^4 + 4^{2019}$ is divisible by 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

**Question:** Is there a simple proof to show that $2019^4 + 4^{2019}$ is divisible by 5?

**Attempts:** I know that this can be done with modular arithmetic by using the fact that if $a = b\mod n$, then $a^k = b^k \mod n$. Is there a way that it could be done without modular arithmetic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement), it can be seen that

$2019^4+4^{2019}=(2020-1)^4+(5-1)^{2019}=(1+5n) + (-1 + 5m)$ is divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler proof would be as follows:
The last digit of $2019^4$ is $1$.  This is because $9*1$ ends with $9$ and $9*9$ ends with $1$. Now $1*9$ is $9$ so it is not difficult to see that this pattern repeats and a number ending with $9$ raised to an even power ends with $1$ because of this continuous cycle.
With a similar cyclic reasoning we find that $4^{2019}$ ends with $4$ because $4^{odd}$ ends with 4.
Adding the two numbers together we find that the sum ends with the number $5$.
Hence the number is divisible by $5$.

Answer (score 1):

Modular arithmetic is the study of remainders, so any proof of divisibility is going to come down to showing that the remainder is 0. But there are proofs where modular arithmetic is not as obvious. For instance, "last digit" is really the same as mod 10, but people are used to seeing what happens with the last digit without studying modular arithmetic theory. We can see that 2019*2019 will have a last digit of 1, and when we multiply by 2019 again, we get a last digit of 9, then when we multiply again we get 1. Similarly, 4 gets us 6, 4, 6, 4, ... 4. So when we add them together, the last digit is 5, which means it's divisible by 5.

Answer (score 0):

Another way without modular arithmetic or binomial theorem:
$$2019^4 + 4^{2019} =2019^4-4^4 + 4^{2019}+4^4 = 2015\cdot a + 4^4\left(4^{2015}+1\right) =2015\cdot a + 5\cdot4^4\cdot b$$

Comment: The logic is far from obvious.